# Oracle - Select where max date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select only customers **that don't have a ticket with competence date** '01/01/2019', I mean the last ticket was from '01/12/2018' to '31/12/2018'

I cannot use max as 'where max(date) = '

How can I do this?

TICKET TABLE:

CUSTUMER ID | TICKET NUMBER | COMPETENCE_DATE

I need to get the custumers that DON'T have a ticket for january, I mean, their last ticket was from 2018

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You want to select customers. So there is a customer table? The customers have tickets. So there is a ticket table? Show the tables and describe how they are related.

Comment: What does 2018 have to do with it? Are there only tickets for 2018 and 2019 in the table? Does every customer have at least one ticket entry?

Comment: You didn't say what RDBMS you are using.  Different systems have different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want customers whose maximum date is in a particular range, use `group by` and `having`:

```
select customerid
from t
group by customerid
having max(competence_date) >= date '2018-12-01' and
       max(competence_date) < date '2019-01-01';
```

Comment: And my lack of basic knowledge strikes again. I don't know why other people are so confused, thats what I need, thanks

Comment: `having max(competence_date) between date '2018-12-01' and date '2018-12-31'`

Comment: @dougp: what about competence_date at 4pm on 12/31 ?  The solution that Gordon proposed follows the best practice pattern working with date and datetime ranges. It seems like going to `BETWEEN ...AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59'` would be fix, but then what about time resolutions better than a second, we'd need to add `.997` ... and it's a game of smaller and smaler gaps. 
 It's just much easier on the future reader if we make our intent clear... including all datetime values on 2018-12-31, we're better off with *less than* '2019-01-01'.

Comment: @dougp: When I'm looking at SQL with  `between .. AND DATE '2018-12-31'` I'm left wondering about the strange specification,  we include exactly at midnight on 12/31, but nothing after midnight... that's a strange specification. And I'm thinking that wasn't the actual specification, and that the developer that wrote that SQL didn't actually test it.

Comment: @spencer7593:  My code produces exactly the same output as Gordon's.  Both are correct.  tramada specified dates, not datetimes.  4:00 PM on 2018-12-31 is still 2018-12-31.  Between is inclusive.  Since we're working with dates, my between statement includes 2018-12-01 through 2018-12-31, regardless of time-of-day.  If the spec involved datetimes, my response would have been different.

Comment: @dougp: Oracle `DATE` datatype includes both date and time components. I agree. If there's a row in the table that has `competence_date` value of '2018-12-31 16:00',  Gordon's query will include it. The code in your comment does not match the same specification. It's relying on "special case" rules (there no time components in stored `competence_date` values on 12/31) i.e. take that same code to the more general case, and it doesn't work. It just makes sense to use the same pattern, the one that works in the general case. There's no advantage using *different* patterns.

Comment: @spencer7593:  You're right.  I'm used to dealing with MS SQL, which separates date from datetime.

Answer (score 0):

[HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select [CUSTOMER ID]

from TICKET

group by [CUSTOMER ID]

having max(COMPETENCE_DATE) < {d '2019-01-01'}
    or max(COMPETENCE_DATE) is null
```

Comment: Doh!  Gordon beat me to the submit button.